# WYGWAM stripping classes and styles

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

If I add this code using WYGWAM source

```
<h2 class="section-title">Some<span class="blue-text long-word">Title</span></h2>
```

and publish, it works fine.

But if I go back and edit the entry and click source again all the classes are removed.

How do I keep WYGWAM from removing all my classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to *Add-ons > Modules > Wygwam > Editor Configurations* and select the configuration you want to edit.

Look for the *Restrict allowed HTML?* setting and make sure it is set to *No.*

[image: wygwam restrict html setting]